# Double or multiple lines gap errors between paragraphs

Tags: line-spacing

I'm using a latex template for writing my manuscript. There are double or multiple spaces between paragraphs even though I didn't use the \newline command nor hit enter key. This occurs especially when I have a figure(s) or table(s) in the corresponding section. On some pages, the paragraphs do not enter a new line even though they are supposed to (for example, there is no space between a section header and the paragraph below it). Currently, I use \Vspace to solve this problem but it still does not seem to be the best solution because I have to manually adjust all the spaces throughout the whole manuscript. May I know if there is any better solution for this?

Here are the commands I use to solve this problem.

```
\vspace{-10pt}
\vspace{29pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Without showing your code, it is very difficult to provide suggestions, please provide `MWE` of your code

Comment: any use of vspace in a document is usually wrong but as you have given no examples impossible to say what you should do instead

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's difficult to picture what is happening without an example.  Please add a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem.  It should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have no idea what you have speciifed in your code; what you describe is not the normal behaviour. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}) that we can compile that shows the problem and how you tried to resolve it.